# Android download and persist a lot of images in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download, universal-image-loader

In my Android application I would like to download a certain number of photos which are linked to points on a map. For example, I have ten points on a map and I have 5 or 6 photos for each point.

At the begining I get 5 or 6 URL (http://theimageurls.com/image.jpg) per point, and for each photo,

- I want to download them
- I want to save them in the device.

Of course, everything's done in background.
The problem is that sometimes my images are not persisted... but the problem is very irregular and can be encountered on whatever image...

here is my code :

For each point, **loadPictures()** is called :

```
private void loadPictures(final KickstartrGeolocPoint point) {

    //Photos : get directory path
    final File pointDir = FileUtils.getPointPhotoDir(getActivity(), point);

    //set boolean to true if the point has photos not downloaded.
    ArrayList<String> photosNotDownloaded = getPhotosNotDownloaded(point, pointDir);
    if(photosNotDownloaded.size()!=0){
        point.setPhoto(true);
        kickstartrGeolocService.updatePoint(currentPoint);
    }else{
        fillPointData(point);
        return;
    }

    //for each urls, download and save photo
    for(final String url : photosNotDownloaded){
        if (!Utils.isValidUrl(url)) continue;
        BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromUrl(url, new OnBitmapRetrievedListener() {
            @Override
            public void bitmapRetrieved(Bitmap bitmap) {
                LogWrapper.debug(getClass(), "Ready to be saved");
                persistImageforPoint(point, pointDir, bitmap, FileUtils.getFileNameFromUrl(url));
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                LogWrapper.debug(getClass(), "Image downloading... " + imageUri);
                //YOU CAN NOTIFY THE VIEW HERE
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                LogWrapper.debug(getClass(), "Loading failed : " + imageUri);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**getBitmapFromUrl()** is a static method which use an external library called https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.

**getBitmapFromUrl()** :

```
public static void getBitmapFromUrl(String url, final OnBitmapRetrievedListener listener) {
    //final int maxSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_max_size);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(url, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            listener.onLoadingStarted(imageUri,view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            listener.onLoadingFailed(imageUri,view,failReason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            listener.bitmapRetrieved(loadedImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            //do nothing for the moment...
            // TODO notify the UI
        }
    });
}
```

**persistImageforPoint()** is called to save the photo :

```
private void persistImageforPoint(KickstartrGeolocPoint point, File pointDir, Bitmap bitmap, String imageName) {
    // Create a subfolder for each point with its id
    if (!pointDir.exists()) {
        if (!pointDir.mkdirs()) {
            LogWrapper.debug(FileUtils.class, "Failed to create directory");
            return;
        }
    }

    final String fullPath = pointDir.getPath()+File.separator+FileUtils.getPointPhotoPrefix(point)+FileUtils.getFileNameFromUrl(imageName);

    //save the file. Asynchronous task --> do not block the UI
    new BitmapPersist(bitmap,fullPath, new OnBitmapPersistedListener() {
        @Override
        public void persistedSuccessfully() {
            addPhotoView(fullPath);
        }

        @Override
        public void errorInPersistance() {
            LogWrapper.error(getClass(),"Error persisting image with path "+fullPath);
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

Here is my **BitmapPersist** class :

```
public class BitmapPersist extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

private String path;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private OnBitmapPersistedListener onBitmapPersistedListener;

public BitmapPersist(Bitmap bitmap, String path, OnBitmapPersistedListener onBitmapPersistedListener) {
    this.bitmap=bitmap;
    this.path=path;
    this.onBitmapPersistedListener=onBitmapPersistedListener;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            out.close();
        } catch(Throwable ignore) {}
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
    if (success)
        onBitmapPersistedListener.persistedSuccessfully();
    onBitmapPersistedListener.errorInPersistance();
}
}
```

Problem : Sometimes my pictures are not saved, sometimes the application crashes... although everything's done in background threads...

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :** *Maybe I can add precisions on the library I'm using to download images : It's Android-Universal-Image-Loader (link above). This library works with memory cache and... disk cache. Maybe I can look at this cache. Maybe I can change the path of disk cache and save my pictures with that. I'm also looking for someone who knows this library (developped by NOSTRA)... The documentation is quite succinct...*

**SOLUTION :** *Don't need to create 2 Asynctasks : Download the picture synchronously and then persist it in the same asynctask.*

Comment: What is the cause of the crash? Post logs

Comment: I cannot do that right now because i'm not working on it today. But I'll do that, yes ! Just wait few hours... ;)

Comment: Ok, I think i've solved my problem. I didn't need 2 Asynctasks : I've developed only one asynctask which download (synchronously) and persist at the same time.